# Find $\lambda>0$ in Sobolev-Gagliardo-Niremberg remark

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality, calculus-of-variations

I started in the following way:

$$1= \int_{_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}} g_{\lambda}^{p^*} (y) \, dy, \; \text{where } g_{\lambda} = (\lambda + |y|^{p'})^{\frac{p-n}{p}} \text{ and }  p^* = \frac{pn}{p} $$

Then,
$$1= \int_{_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}} g_{\lambda}^{p^*} (y) \, dy = \int_{_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}} (\lambda + |y|^{p'})^{-n} \, dy $$

And, by using the fact that $g_\lambda$ is a radial function and $n$ dimensional polar coordinates:

$$1=n \cdot w_n \cdot \int_{_{0}}^{\infty} (\lambda + \rho^{p'})^{-n} \cdot \rho^{n-1} \, d\rho$$
I could use that $n \cdot w_n = Area(S^{n-1}$), with radius $\rho$. I'm not sure how to continue form this point in order to find the form of $\lambda$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.